# Access is denied with (Win32PrioritySeparation)

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a problem access to  the (REG_DWORD value) in the (Win32PrioritySeparation)inside the registry of windows 7,
I get [error message: Access is denied]
Can someone help me please

```
    set/p "x="
if %x% EQU b REG add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl /v Win32PrioritySeparation /t REG_DWORD /d 10 /f
if %x% EQU B REG add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl /v Win32PrioritySeparation /t REG_DWORD /d 10 /f
if %x% EQU c REG add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl /v Win32PrioritySeparation /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
if %x% EQU C REG add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl /v Win32PrioritySeparation /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
ECHO.
@pause
```

Comment: The registry does not contain files, it has hives, keys and values.

Comment: access is denied to the (REG_DWORD value) in the (Win32PrioritySeparation)

Comment: Right click your batch and choose Run as administrator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Write access to all keys and values in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE (HKLM) requires administrator privileges and therefore [Noodles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3784455/noodles) is right: you have to run your batch file as administrator.

BTW: Using option `/I` on command `IF` changes the comparison from case-sensitive to case-insensitive.

```
set /P "x="
if /I %x% EQU B REG add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl /v Win32PrioritySeparation /t REG_DWORD /d 10 /f
if /I %x% EQU C REG add HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\PriorityControl /v Win32PrioritySeparation /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
echo.
@pause
```